# How to store function getPageTypeFromDataLayer as a variable and reference the variable?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, data-layers

My function (`getPageTypeFromDataLayer`) is being called multiple times and I think it would be best to store it as a variable and then reference the variable but not sure how to set it up. Can anyone help?

Code:

```
export const getPageTypeFromDataLayer = function () {
    const pageTypeObj = window?.dataLayer?.filter((data) => data.pageType)[0];
    if (pageTypeObj) {
        return pageTypeObj.pageType;
    }
    return "unknown";
};
```

In another section of the code, I reference the function in multiple pages where the data from dataLayer is being pulled. I would like to reference it as a variable instead since it's being called multiple times. Can someone help me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should just be able to do:

```js
  export const getPageTypeFromDataLayer = function () {
    const pageTypeObj = window?.dataLayer?.filter((data) => data.pageType)[0];
    if (pageTypeObj) {
      return pageTypeObj.pageType;
    }
    return "unknown";
  }
```

The returned value can be stored like this: `const value = getPageFromDataLayer()`.

You can call the function in the same file with `getPageTypeFromDataLayer()` and also call it in other files by importing it with `import { getPageTypeFromDataLayer } from './your-file.js'`.

Make sure to add `"type": "module"` to your `package.json`.